# neo4j create relationships from file

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have not been able to create relationships from a file using -c or -f commands as they error out with "Unknown Command":

```
Neo4j-sh (?)$ -file "file:/Users/jdoe/Documents/Test/CreateRelationships.cql" > result.txt;
Neo4j-sh (?)$ -c < /Users/jdoe/Documents/Test/CreateRelationships.cql;
```

I am using Neo4j 2.1.6 and have tried executing from shell console. I have not found any other solutions. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You're passing command line arguments to the **UNIX shell** from inside of the **Neo4j shell**.  That's the confusion.  I can tell that's happening because you pasted the `Neo4j-sh (?)$` prompt, rather than a UNIX shell prompt, something like `$` or `[user@host foo]$`

When you're at the command line, you should do something like this:

```
neo4j-shell -file "file:/Users/jdoe/Documents/Test/CreateRelationships.cql" > result.txt;
```

The confusion here is that the neo4j-shell is not the same thing as the UNIX shell.  Things like the `>` operator only works with the UNIX shell, ditto arguments like `-file`.

Comment: Can this be done from a windows machine? The only documentation I found on line was to run commands from Neo4j shell:C:\Program Files (x86)\Neo4j Community\bin\Neo4jShell.bat
the only solutions that I've been able to get to work is to create a csv file with two columns of account IDs and then use the following:
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 100 LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/Users/jdoe/Documents/Test/Relationships.csv" AS line MATCH (a:Employer {accountid: toInt(line.EmployerID)}),(b:Employee {accountid: toInt(line.EmploteeID)}) CREATE (a)-[:Hired]->(b);

Comment: If you're using the Windows shell, you can Start -> Run then type in "cmd".  This will give you a shell.  Then type the full path to that bat file, i.e. "C:\Program Files (x86)\Neo4j Community\bin\Neo4jShell.bat" -file "file:/Users/jdoe/Documents/Test/CreateRelationships.cql" and that's basically using the windows shell to do the same thing